# Ability to copy and paste into a system but not out of?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm looking for the ability to copy in to an RDP session but not copy out of. Is something like this possible? If not, should I be using user activity monitoring software to alert when someone copies out of the system?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a separate protocol, such as SFTP. Set up [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/free_sftp_client_for_windows) client, for example, and as "belt and suspenders", add a firewall rule on the machine you wish to protect to prevent outbound SFTP transfer.

That said, if you use Remote Desktop to a PC, you enable the user to open files and view them, so you could not prevent screen scraping bringing over data. The only way I can think to prevent that is to create a user with limited access, so the files are inaccessible.

Comment: Thats a good point, I was thinking of using user activity monitoring software to be alerted if they are screenshoting or moving files out of the systems. That would allow them to copy into but we would be alerted if they attempt to move anything out.